# Trying to find how to stop refresh when src changed

Tags: javascript, html

I created a code that takes the content (url) in the TXT file and places it in the  src.

I tried to make sure that once the content in the TXT file changes, the page refreshes and then the src changes too,
But instead the page automatically refreshes after every second and the player can not play the link.

**How to do that only after the content in the TXT file is replaced will the page refresh.**

```html
<video width="500px" height="300px" src="Texttochange"></video>

<script>
    function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "test.txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                 document.querySelector('video').src = allText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
    setInterval(readTextFile, 1000);

</script>
```

Here **test.txt**

```
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4
```

Comment: Have you tried storing the allText variable and comparing that each time you check for updates?

Comment: How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand you right, you need to check `src` for changes like:

```
if (allText !== document.querySelector('video').src)
```

Pro tip: Call function again if request is done instead of timer will prevent problems.

```
function readTextFile()
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "test.txt", false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                if (allText !== document.querySelector('video').src)
                 document.querySelector('video').src = allText;
            }
            //setInterval(readTextFile, 1000);
            readTextFile();
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Comment: It does not because `rawFile.responseText;` isn't changing.